Movie of alien cop chasing alien criminal on earth
I saw this film sometime between 1980 to 1992. It is set in a city in the USA. 
In the movie, an alien criminal comes to Earth with the ability to take over control of humans (and in one case a dog) by passing from one to the next entering them through their mouths. An alien cop, chasing after the criminal, joins forces with an local police officer from Earth to hunt him down.
The criminal works his way to taking over a presidential candidate.

This is definitely The Hidden - it has it all: alien criminal who can switch bodies, a senator who is taken over and announces he wants to run for president...

Argh, too slow, wanted to answer this right away. Great movie, love Kyle MacLachlan.

One of the great car chase / car crash movies of all time.
